# pandas.Panel best practice: what axis should hold the DatetimeIndex?

Tags: python, pandas

**Background**

The pandas bug detailed on [GitHub](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/8251) hints that the pandas developers are assuming the `DatetimeIndex` is index 1 (major_axis).

I have two primary use cases for the panel:

1. A collection of time `Series` indexed by labels, typically accessed like: `panel.loc[:,'ABC', 'XYZ']`
2. A collection of `DataFrame`s indexed by time, typically accessed like: `panel.loc[Timestamp('2011-01-01'), :, :]`

In the first case, we prefer the memory layout to be such that the Series we typically access is memory contiguous. In the second case, we might prefer that at least one axis of the accessed DataFrame is memory contiguous or we might prefer to follow a convention keeping the `DatetimeIndex` on the same axis where possible.

In short, we might prefer to use the panel in a 'typical' way, because if our usage matches that of the majority (and the pandas developers in particular) we're more likely to have elegant code (eg default parameters work more often) and less likely to come across surprising behaviour.

**Questions**

1. What axis (if any) *typically* holds the `DatetimeIndex`?
2. Which panel index is memory contiguous?

Comment: `.values.flags` suggest it's C-contiguous (where DataFrames are F-contiguous). To be honest, in the past, I've just permuted and seen what's fastest for the use case.

Comment: pandas is not assuming anything for your axis. That is a bug. You would need to show what you are *doing* with the panel for me to give you an answer here. Why do you care if its contiguous (that is an impl detail).

Comment: I wouldn't care about memory layout except for micro-optimization. I'd expect with a large sizes selecting series where each series is contiguous would be much faster, so it would be nice to know.

Comment: I'm more interested in following convention - making my code more maintainable by the average programmer. For example, you'd always expect a dataframe to have the DatetimeIndex as the index not the columns - doing the transpose forces people to rethink their mental model. I'd prefer to follow the crowd unless I've a good reason to do otherwise. Since I found the bug and that the unittest factory creates a Panel with DatetimeIndex on axis=1, I thought I'd ask if there's a convention.